# Oracle: Iterate over table and print out an xml file for every row name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table where, for example, there is a id number in each row, but it is not continuous (1,2,4,6,7). Now I want to create an XML file for each number, which also contains certain other data, but which are not important for the question.

My question now is how do I set up this for loop to pull out the number one by one and transfer it to my PL SQL? And i need to write an export date into the table after the export. Thanks for your help.

Table
id_order | export date

This is my code for the xml files and now i need a loop for the id_order Number:

```
declare
fhandle  utl_file.file_type;

-- Output Variablen
output_intro varchar2(23000);

ID_order NUMBER := 1;
filename varchar2(100) := 'test.xml';

-- Intro
BEGIN
fhandle := utl_file.fopen('EXPORT', filename , 'w');
begin
    SELECT 
    '<"ID">'|| ID ||'</ID>' || CHR(10)

    into output_intro FROM Table
    WHERE ID = ID_order;
    exception
      when others THEN
          output_intro := 'Issue Intro';
end;

BEGIN
    utl_file.put(fhandle, output_intro);
END;

utl_file.fclose(fhandle);
exception
when others then
  dbms_output.put_line('ERROR: ' || SQLCODE
                    || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
  raise;
end;
/
```

Comment: Use a cursor for looping.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to simnply return the 'ID' value for each row as XML, you should look at the SQLXML functions.

In your case, try this:

`SELECT XMLFOREST(id) FROM table`

It handles multiple columns easily:

`SELECT XMLFOREST(id, col2, col3,) FROM table`

To nest this between 'Data' element:

`SELECT XMLELEMENT( "Data", XMLFOREST(id) ) FROM table`

Putting it all together:

```
DECLARE
   l_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   l_xmltype XMLType;
BEGIN
   SELECT XMLELEMENT( "Data", XMLFOREST(id) )
   INTO   l_xmltype 
   FROM table;
   l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen ('EXPORT', 'output.xml', 'w');
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(l_file , l_xmltype.getStringVal( ));
   UTL_FILE.fclose (l_file);
END;
/
```

Note if the XML size is greater than 32K then you will need to write tout the the file in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cursor to create a loop

```
-- Declare a cursor
Cursor Cur is select * from YourTable where YourCondition;
Row_ Cur%rowtype;

begin
    -- Open the cursor
    Open Cur;

    -- Loop over the cursor rows
    loop 
        -- Fetch every into the object Row_
        fetch cur into Row_;

        -- Exit when no rows found
        exit when Cur%notfound;

        -- Perform the export to a file here
        --You can access Row_ columns by appending columns to Row_. For example : Row_.FirstName
    end loop;
    Close Cur;
end;
```